# mysql reports lost connection to mysql server during query for optimize table command

Tags: mysql

Whenever I try optimize table command, mysql always gives me the following error:

2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

What is wrong with it?

Edit:

Here are all the parameters related to timeout:

+-----------------------------+----------+

| Variable_name               | Value    |

+-----------------------------+----------+

| connect_timeout             | 10       |

| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |

| have_statement_timeout      | YES      |

| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1        |

| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |

| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | OFF      |

| interactive_timeout         | 28800    |

| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |

| net_read_timeout            | 30       |

| net_write_timeout           | 60       |

| rpl_stop_slave_timeout      | 31536000 |

| slave_net_timeout           | 60       |

| wait_timeout                | 28800    |

+-----------------------------+----------+

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the timeout on your server.

Adjust below settings based on your requirement. If you are running MySQL on CentOS/Redhat machine, you can find the configuration file in `/etc/my.cnf`

```
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
```

Comment: Increase it as per as your liking and see if that changes anything.